# Finding the equation of a cubic polynomial $f(x)$, then solving $f(x) = 120$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> Determine algebraically the value(s) of $x$ where the cubic function that has zeroes at $2$, $3$, and $-5$, and passes through the point $(4,36)$ has a value of $120$.

It is clear that I need to solve for $x$ when $y=120$, but the wording has left me confused and not sure how to approach it.

Comment: removing the relative clause "that has zeroes at 2, 3, and −5, and passes through the point (4,36)", we have left the main clause "Determine algebraically the value(s) of x where the cubic function has a value of 120.". In Math, English Grammar is your friend.

Answer (score 7):

You should read it in two parts:

> 1. Find the unique cubic polynomial $y = f(x)$ that has zeroes at $2$, $3$, and $-5$ and passes through the point $(4,36)$.
> 2. Find all values of $x$ such that $f(x) = 120$.

As a hint for the first part, note that the zeroes tell us that the function has the form:
$$
f(x) = a(x - 2)(x - 3)(x + 5)
$$
where $a$ is some scaling factor that we can solve for by using the given point.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18547/discussion-on-answer-by-adriano-finding-the-equation-of-a-cubic-polynomial-fx).